# Spring MVC + Spring Data JPA. Правильный путь к applicationContextMVC.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Я использую Spring MVC и в качестве ORM использую Spring Data JPA. Для того, чтобы создать объект репозитория, мне нужно узнать правильный путь к моему `applicationContextMVC.xml`, но как бы я не пытался, `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` не может найти этот файлик. Подскажите пожалуйста, какой правильный путь будет в моём случае? Вот структура проекта:

[image: Вот структура проекта]

```java
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String sayHello(Model model){
        //                                             !!! ПРОБЛЕМА ТУТ !!!
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContextMVC.xml");

        CountryRepository countryRepository = context.getBean(CountryRepository.class);

        model.addAttribute("country", countryRepository.getOne(1L));

        return "index";
    } // sayHello.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш файл не находится на пути classpath, попробуйте

```java
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("../WEB-INF/applicationContextMVC.xml");
```

Можно использовать также

```java
XmlWebApplicationContext("/WEB-INF/applicationContextMVC.xml");
```